# Circular dependencies error with axios in Svelte

Tags: axios, svelte, circular-dependency

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import { onMount } from "svelte";
let events = [];

onMount(async () => {
  try 
  {
     const res = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
     console.log(res);
     events = res.data;
  } 
  catch (error) 
  {
      console.log(error);
  }

});
</script>

<div>
{JSON.stringify(events)} 
</div>
```

With this simple example, I get following error.

(!) **Circular dependencies**
node_modules/axios/lib/defaults.js -> node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js -> node_modules/axios/lib/defaults.js
node_modules/axios/lib/defaults.js -> node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js -> node_modules/axios/lib/defaults.js?commonjs-proxy -> node_modules/axios/lib/defaults.js

I am using axios v0.22.0 and svelte 3.43.1 with rollup

**Can anyone help me out? I checked with axios 0.21.4, the error does not show up.**

Answer (score 1):

It's related to this [issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4177). Should be fixed soon.
In the meantime, use version 0.21.4